# Accessing another route in IIS returns error

Tags: reactjs, iis-8, react-router-dom

#### Scenario:

I'm using React to be able to do my project.
I'm also using the `react-router-dom` to route the application. For this routes I have the following code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import isAuthenticated from '~/services/auth/auth'
import history from './history'

import Login from '~/pages/login'
import Menu from '~/pages/menumain'

/* *** SISTEMA *** */
/* Permissões */
import Permissions from '~/pages/sistema/permissoes/permissoes'
import AddPermission from '~/pages/sistema/permissoes/addpermission'

/* *** CADASTRO *** */
/* Usuário */
import ReadUsers from '~/pages/cadastro/usuario/listusers'
import CreateUser from '~/pages/cadastro/usuario/cadusers'
import UpdateUser from '~/pages/cadastro/usuario/edituser'
/* Empresa */
import ReadCompany from '~/pages/cadastro/empresa/listEmpresa'
import CreateCompany from '~/pages/cadastro/empresa/cadEmpresa'
import UpdateCompany from '~/pages/cadastro/empresa/editEmpresa'
/* Contas */
import ReadAccount from '~/pages/cadastro/contas/index'
import CreateAccounts from '~/pages/cadastro/contas/create'
import UpdateAccounts from '~/pages/cadastro/contas/update'
/* Fechamento */
import ReadClosure from '~/pages/cadastro/fechamento/index'
/* *** FLUXO DE CAIXA *** */
import FluxoCaixa from '~/pages/fluxoCaixa/index'

/* *** Ajuda ** */
import Sobre from '~/pages/ajuda/sobre'

/* *** Erro *** */
import Error from '~/pages/error'

import PermissonStatus from '~/pages/getpermissions'

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
<Route
    {...rest}
    render={props => {
    const isAuth = isAuthenticated()
    return isAuth ? (
        <Component {...props} />
    ) : (
        <Redirect
        to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }}
        />
    )
    }}
/>
)

const Routes = () => (
<BrowserRouter history={history}>
    <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route exact path="/fluxocaixa" component={FluxoCaixa} />
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Menu} />

    {/* *** SISTEMA *** */}
    {/* Permissões */}
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/permissions" component={Permissions} />
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/permissionModels" component={AddPermission} />
    {/* Usuário */}
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/readusers" component={ReadUsers} />
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/createuser" component={CreateUser} />
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/updateuser" component={UpdateUser} />
    {/* Empresa */}
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/readcompany" component={ReadCompany} />
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/createcompany" component={CreateCompany} />
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/updatecompany" component={UpdateCompany} />
    {/* Contas */}
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/readaccounts" component={ReadAccount} />
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/createaccounts" component={CreateAccounts} />
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/updateaccounts" component={UpdateAccounts} />
    {/* Fechamento */}
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/readclosure" component={ReadClosure} />

    {/* *** Ajuda *** */}
    {/* Sobre */}
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/about" component={Sobre} />

    <PrivateRoute exact path="/permstatus" component={PermissonStatus} />

    <Route component={Error} />
    <Route exact path="/teste" component={Permissions} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
)
export default Routes
```

#### Goal:

> I post this code in IIS 8.5 and if I acess the route http//localhost:3000 , it returns the desired route.

#### Problem:

**when i acess http//localhost:3000/fluxocaixa i received this error:**

[image]

**Anything solution for this error?**

Comment: https://medium.com/@mateioprea/setting-up-a-react-app-with-react-router-in-iis-71cb86aee376 Lesson 101.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue you first need to install the URL rewrite module.

download link:
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

add below rule in your web.config file(if not then create web.config file first)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
 <rules>
 <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" />
 <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
 </rule>
 </rules>
 </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Again build the application in prod mode and browse.